# Como obtengo el valor contenido en el boton en lugar de una lista de valores (datos de Firestore)

Tags: javascript, firebase

Quiero obtener un valor "X" contenido en un botón al momento de hacer click, pero estoy obteniendo la lista completa de valores contenidos en multiples botones. Los botones son construidos en base a los datos obtenidos de una base de datos externa (FIRESTORE)

En HTML genero una tabla llamada "tablay", que a su vez se alimenta de un código en el archivo JS
El archivo JS obtiene datos/valores de FIRESTORE y genera un botón por cada registro en la base de datos

**EL HTML se ve así**

```
<div data-operation class="card"> <!-- Se crea un card para contener los botones -->
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row" id="tablay"> <!-- Se insertan los botones a partir de un código de JS -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Al inicio del JS se asigna el valor del data-operation a operationsButtons

```
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
```

**El JS contiene 2 partes, la primera es como sigue:**

```
//Leer documentos READ
        var tabla2 = document.getElementById('tablay'); // se crea la tabla2 como variable para contener el HTML que contiene los botones
// ahora se obtienen los valores de la base de datos para crear los botones
        db.collection("productospdv").orderBy("secuencia","asc").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            tabla2.innerHTML =''; // se limpia cualquier valor anterior del innerHTML
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                var arreglo = [`${doc.data().Nombre}`]; // se crea el arreglo para generar los botones
// se crea el HTML para crear los botones
                tabla2.innerHTML +=
                `
                <tr>                
<!-- se define el espacio/tamaño -->
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-2 col-xlg-3">
<!-- se da una clase para dar un comportamiento al botón -->                       
                    <div class="card card-hover">
<!-- se asigna un color de background basado en un registro de la base de datos -->
                            <div class="box ${doc.data().background} text-center">
<!-- se dan características al texto y el icono -->
                            <h1 class="font-light text-white"><i class="mdi ${doc.data().icono}"></i></h1>
<!-- se da el texto obtenido del campo "Nombre" desde la base de datos -->
                            <h6 class="text-white">${doc.data().Nombre}</h6>
                        </div>                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </tr>
<!-- se cierra la creación del innerHTML -->
                `
            });
        });
```

**La segunda parte del JS es un eventlistener para identificar cuando se presiona un botón:**

```
// listener para obtener el dato cuando se hace click en el botón
operationButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // el valor se manda a la consola para verificar los valores
    console.log(button.innerText);
  })
})
```

Pero los datos que obtengo son múltiples, en lugar de solo obtener el valor del botón seleccionado, teniendo en la consola los valores:
boton1, boton2, boton3

en lugar de solo: boton3

Comment: Te falto agregar el código con el que insertas los botones.

Comment: @Triby los botones se insertan por medio del innerHTML que esta dentro del JS que marqué como: "primer parte"

Comment: @Triby edité la pregunta, me parece que ya contiene los elementos necesarios para que tu o alguien mas pudiera responder, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

> Una expresión de función flecha tiene una sintaxis más compacta que una expresión de función regular, por lo que son una buena alternativa a estas últimas, aunque no tienen su propio *this*, *arguments*, *super* o *new.target*. Estas expresiones no son adecuadas para ser utilizadas como métodos, y no pueden ser usadas como constructores. [Funciones Flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions)

Entonces, la solución es usar una función anónima, donde sí tienes acceso a `this` para identificar cada elemento:

```js
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]');
// listener para obtener el dato cuando se hace click en el botón
operationButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // el valor se manda a la consola para verificar los valores
    console.log(this.innerText);
  });
});
```

```html
<button data-operation="dato1">Botón 1</button>
<button data-operation="dato2">Botón 2</button>
<button data-operation="dato3">Botón 3</button>
<button data-operation="dato4">Botón 4</button>
<button data-operation="dato5">Botón 5</button>
```